# JSP/JSTL Error in Eclipse - Undefined attribute name

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jstl, taglib

Servlet code snippet:

```
// check/get session
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    ArrayList<LineItem> transactions = (ArrayList<LineItem>)session.getAttribute("transactions");
.....
// set session
session.setAttribute("transactions", transactions);
```

JSP code snippet:

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" %>
.....
<c:forEach var="item" transactions="${transactions}">  
            <tr>
                <td>${item.action}</td>
                <td>${item.product.getCode}</td>
                <td>${item.product.getArtist}</td>
                <td>${item.product.getTitle}</td>
                <td>${item.product.getCategory}</td>
                <td>${item.product.getDescription}</td>
                <td>${item.product.getPriceCurrency}</td>
            </tr>
 </c:forEach>
```

Exception:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/Maintenance] threw exception [/product_audit.jsp (line: 52, column: 4) Attribute transactions invalid for tag forEach according to TLD] with root cause
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /product_audit.jsp (line: 52, column: 4) Attribute transactions invalid for tag forEach according to TLD
```

I'm using JSTL 1.0 (declared in manifest and verified the .jar file). Any suggestions?

Comment: edit your foreach loop like= <c:forEach var="item" items="${transactions}">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is clear:

> Attribute transactions invalid for tag forEach according to TLD

The problem is here:

```html
<c:forEach var="item" transactions="${transactions}">
<!--                  ^ there is no such attribute -->
```

Change `transactions` by `items`:

```html
<c:forEach var="item" items="${transactions}">
```

Comment: First, thank you for editing my question. Secondly, I've tried your suggestion already and to no avail. Any other ideas?

Comment: @JustinHeist check if you haven't done the same mistake on other parts of your JSPs. Provide the current stacktrace you have.

Comment: My apologies, when I had 'items' I was using a different taglib. Thank you for your help.